# Outlook: turn off silent alert on successive emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Outlook 2007 provides a little corner popup with an audio warning. However if there is a short period where after receiving an email the popup will occur, but the audio will not upon new emails.

From looking at the [alert options](http://www.timeatlas.com/email/outlook/conditional_desktop_alerts_in_microsoft_outlook), I don't see this "feature." Is there any way to turn it off?

Edit:: So I would want to hear a sound ever time an email is received.

Comment: So, you want to hear the sound every time the popup appears, right?

Comment: Or you don't, right?

Comment: Yes, I would like to hear a sound whenever I receive an email.

Comment: I think you should change the title - how to play a sound every time I receive an email

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add a rule for all incoming emails to play a sound?

[image: Play a sound]

Comment: But that has a restriction on Who and where it is going to be placed. And I bet Outlook's silence feature will still override it.

Comment: That was just an example. You can check the play a sound option only.
Apply this rule after the message arrives and play a sound"